# RMStore In App Purchase Unknown Product Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I have spent all day trying to get an in app purchase to work in my app, and everything that I have tried to make it work results in a 'Unkown Product Identifier' response from RMStore. I have tried everything on this list: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

My Code is:

```
if ([RMStore canMakePayments]) {

    _products = @[@"com.afterdark.afterdark.usersaleslisting"];

    [[RMStore defaultStore] requestProducts:[NSSet setWithArray:_products] success:^(NSArray *products, NSArray *invalidProductIdentifiers) {

        NSLog(@"Request Success");
        NSString *productID = _products[0];
        SKProduct *product = [[RMStore defaultStore] productForIdentifier:productID];
        NSLog(@"IAP ID: %@",productID);
        NSLog(@"IAP TITLE: %@",product.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"IAP PRICE: %@",[RMStore localizedPriceOfProduct:product]);

        [[RMStore defaultStore] addPayment:productID success:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {

            NSLog(@"Payment Succes");

        } failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Payment Failed: %@",error.localizedDescription);

        }];


    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@",error.localizedDescription);

    }];

}
```

Itunes Connect - In App Purchases:

[image: Itunes Connect - In App Purchases]

Xcode - In App Purchases Capability

[image]

I have completely run out of ideas of how to get this to work, anyone have any ideas? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have finally got this working. I contacted apple and it turns out the only reason it wasn't working is because something had gone wrong on their servers when I created the IAP in iTunes Connect, they promptly resolved the issue.